# Update on join in Hive

Tags: hive

I'm trying to understand how to update a column in a Hive table, based on an id match with a different table.
That is, I have a table 'users', with columns 'UID' (string), 'isVerified' (boolean) and a lot more columns. Then I have a second table 'users_verified', with just 1 column 'UID' (string). I'm trying to do something to the effect of

```
UPDATE users SET isVerified = 1 
WHERE UID in (SELECT UID from users_verified);
```

However neither this nor UPDATE ON JOIN queries seem supported by Hive, and it seems I need to use an INSERT OVERWRITE statement instead. Can anyone give me an example of how that might work?

Comment: If you need ACID, read this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-WhatisACIDandwhyshouldyouuseit?

Comment: Any tech on hadoop  (HDFS)is not made or developed  for update on data if still you need the update you have to write select using "INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '<directory>' SELECT * FROM table_name; " snd then drop old table and point new location.  ...